# JavaScript keydown not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

```
$("body").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 116) {
        window.location.href = "google.com";
    }
});
```

I used this code so that every-time someone press f5 it will force them to go to other URL. I tested this with Chrome and it worked fine but with FireFox, nothing happens.

Please help me with this.

Thank you!

Comment: which version of `FireFox` you are using ? try to use `e.keyCode`

Comment: This is a pure guess, but FF protects some system keyboard shortcuts from overriding, like CTRL + D, maybe "The Refresh Button" is also one of these?

Comment: Both `e.which` and `e.keyCode` are deprecated. Use `e.key` instead.

Comment: @connexo Nope, see [e.which](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/#event-which1). Notice, that OP has a jQuery event, not native.

Comment: Well I wouldn't consider jQuery for a second in the first place to achieve that. Well spotted nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is working fine

```
$(function() {
  $("body").keydown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.which == 116) {
      window.location.href = "http://google.com";
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: just a question, how can I detech if Ctrl +f5 is pressed? like this: `e.which == 116 && e.which == ctrlKey`

Comment: something like this if (e.which == 116 && e.ctrlKey)